# Is OneDrive Rest API Free to use?

Tags: onedrive

Is OneDrive Rest API free to use? I can not find any info about pricing for the API anywhere. My client has an office 365 subscription with lots of onedrive storage, but I can't find info about the price of onedrive api.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a customer service question for an off-site vendor. We are not license or pricing support for that vendor. Questions related to programming (code) and use of that API are on-topic here;questions regarding pricing or acceptable use should be addressed directly to that vendor.

Comment: Hi @user1431072, I have the same question, thanks for asking. What did you find out about this? I'd also like to be able to use the OneDrive REST API, and I also have an Office 365 (now called Microsoft 365) subscription, but it seems like you may need an Azure subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API is free.

OneDrive only charges fees if users want to increase the amount of storage they have available.